# Flutter Web: StreamBuilder browser resize & rebuild

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, stream-builder

I have a simple HomePage with a streambuilder listView.  I know that flutter will rebuild/repaint as needed by design but does that mean the StreamBuilder will go get the same data over and over on every rebuild ?

The reason I ask is with every browser resize or browser move from screen 1 to screen 2 I get a complete rebuild/refresh of data ( or so it seems from my console log).  This seems highly inefficient/unnecessary for bigger projects with larger data sets.

Can I, should I, try to prevent streamBuilder from getting the same data on browser resizing ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, import this.

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
```

Now, declare AsyncMemoizer.

```
final AsyncMemoizer memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
```

Use it with StreamBuilder widget in stream parameter.

```
stream: memoizer.runOnce(() => YOUR STREAM DATA),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this gives me a "The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<dynamic>'." Error for this line of code: " stream: memoizer.runOnce(() => fsRef.doc(coID).snapshots()),"

Comment: can you share code snippet of stream method?

Comment: did you solve the issue?